# RN JS TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.link.photo.photo_604')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get data, the data is output to the console, but the error occurs all smoothly...

JOSN array vk neewsfeed !

code:

```js
export function ParseAttach(content) {
  if (content == undefined) return true;
  let img = [];
  let index = 0;

  content.map(function (item, i) {
    if (item.type == 'photo' || item.type == 'graffiti') {
      index++;
      img[0] = index;
      img[index] = item.photo.photo_604;
    } else if (item.type == 'link') {
      index++;
      img[0] = index;
      console.log(item.link.photo.photo_604);
      img[index] = item.link.photo.photo_604;
    }
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fGMf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nFN1.png)

Comment: SHow us what the `item.photo.photo_604` object looks like.

Comment: solved the problem as follows
i create new function

Comment: Sorry opo your comment is practically unreadable.

Comment: Excuse me my english level google translate

Comment: Sorry, I understand the question. I mean the format of your answer in the comment was unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an extra function.

You can do it like:

```js
export function ParseAttach(content) {
  if (content == undefined) return true;
  let img = [];
  let index = 0;

  content.map(function (item, i) {
    if (item.type == 'photo' || item.type == 'graffiti') {
      index++;
      img[0] = index;
      img[index] = item.photo.photo_604;
    } else if (item.type == 'link') {
      index++;
      img[0] = index;
      img[index] = item.link.photo && item.link.photo.photo_604;
    }
  });
}
```